# Custom Console nullPointerException when checking for existing text

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextarea

i have created a custom console for a program. I have a method that adds a message to the console called toConsole this asks for the string where it checks and adds the time to the string. it then goes to my function addConsole which checks if existing text is present if so it will then add the pre-existing text to the new text, else it just puts the new text in. so here is the error.  i may also point out that if i enter text manually on the consoles input text box it does not produce this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.michael.tech.api.console.RunConsole.addConsole(RunConsole.java:188)
    at com.michael.tech.api.console.RunConsole.toConsole(RunConsole.java:204)
    at com.michael.tech.api.console.RunConsole.toConsole(RunConsole.java:223)
    at com.michael.tech.api.testerFile.main(testerFile.java:25)
```

here is the addConsole method

```
private static void addConsole(String s){
    console.setText( ( console.getText().isEmpty()) ? s : (console.getText() + "\n" + s) );
}
```

the toConsole method

```
public static void toConsole(String s, boolean timeStamp, boolean classPath, String className){
        if(s.startsWith("/")){
            doCommand(s);
            return;
        }
        Time t = new Time();
        t.getSYSPrint();
        String time = "[" + t.toMilitary() + "] ";
        if(EchoTime || timeStamp){
            addConsole(time + s);
        }
        else if(classPath){
            addConsole(className);
        }
        else{ 
            addConsole(s);
        }
    }
```

and lastly the Main method in testerFile class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
        RunConsole.startConsole();
        RunConsole.toConsole("test");
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I assume it is some small mistake i overlooked (I hope too).

EDIT:
paste bin to see line numbers

RunConsole class
http://pastebin.com/2yUAwQc5

testerFile class
http://pastebin.com/R5ViLekp

Comment: You need to identify line 188 of RunConsole.java so people know where the exception occurred. But it might be that 'console' isn't given a value before you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `JTextArea` `console` still has its default `null` value as it has not been instantiated. This is because there is no *instance* of `RunConsole` created — Instead, you are accessing the methods of this class in a `static` way:

```
RunConsole.startConsole();
RunConsole.toConsole("test");
```

Using `static` methods is poor design especially since your application needs to have *state*. Make all `static` methods in `RunConsole` instance methods and replace the above lines with:

```
RunConsole runConsole = new RunConsole();
runConsole.startConsole();
runConsole.toConsole("test");
```

Also, when you do this, don't forget to remove your instance created in `startConsole`, otherwise you will not see the initial message from `toConsole`. Change:

```
new RunConsole().setVisible(true);
```

to

```
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Oh no wonder i was getting the nullPointer, however with the instantiated `RunConsole` i get an error-free boot of the console but the `toConsole("test")` is not printed in the console once its booted. I did remove the static modifier from the methods.